# Scrapy: scrapy not calling the callback

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to write a scraper using scrapy that takes in input arguments. The init method is as follows:

```
 def __init__(self, inputfile="input.csv", *args, **kwargs):

        super(DemoSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        custom_settings = {
            'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
                'ScrapySpider.pipelines.PostProcessingHtml': 300,
                'ScrapySpider.pipelines.GetShortDesc': 301,
                # 'ScrapySpider.pipelines.Database': 302
            }
        }
        #Reading input file to get the input data
        InputData = ReadParamsFromCSV(inputfile)
        start_urls = []
        rules = []
        for i in range(0, len(InputData)):
            # for i in range(1, 2):
            start_urls += [InputData[i][0]]
            rules.append(
                Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=InputData[i][1]),
                     callback='parse_items',
                     cb_kwargs={'InputData': InputData[i]},
                     follow=True))
```

This code is not calling back `parse_items` functions. What am I missing here? I could not find a lot of details about the init method itself, so I am not sure what should I return here.

Comment: What’s the structure of the input.csv file?

Comment: url;link_regex;title_css;job_desc_xpath;company_name Delimiter is semicolon

Comment: The problem that I am trying to solve is to send `inputfile` parameter as a commandline argument, which I can pass to the function `ReadParamsFromCSV`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the rules before 'super'.

Also custom_settings and start_urls need to be a class attribute.

(you can also update custom_settings but it's easier to take it out of the init function if you don't need to change it dynamically).

```
custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'ScrapySpider.pipelines.PostProcessingHtml': 300,
        'ScrapySpider.pipelines.GetShortDesc': 301,
        # 'ScrapySpider.pipelines.Database': 302
        }
    }

 def __init__(self, inputfile="input.csv", *args, **kwargs):
    #Reading input file to get the input data
    InputData = ReadParamsFromCSV(inputfile)
    self.start_urls = []
    rules = []
    for i in range(0, len(InputData)):
        # for i in range(1, 2):
        self.start_urls += [InputData[i][0]]
        rules.append(
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=InputData[i][1]),
                 callback='parse_items',
                 cb_kwargs={'InputData': InputData[i]},
                 follow=True))
                 
    super(DemoSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It is still not calling `parse-items` callback function.

Comment: @lokitkhemka do you get some kind of error? is it loading the start_urls fine?

Comment: No errors. URLs are fine, they were working previously. I think the program is not calling callback. The input data is as below: `https://careers.leidos.com/search/jobs?q=computational;^(.*leidos.com/jobs/[0-9]+);//h1[1]/text();//*[@class = "job-details-description page-content"];Leidos` The delimiter is semi-colon

Comment: It is working as usual as soon as I remove the init method declaration and super init call.